# How to extract the Day, Month and Year from the date?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I just cant figure out how to get the day, the months and the year from the dates.

Here it is the eloquent

```
 public function query(Detail $model)
    {
    return $model->newQuery()->leftjoin('fishers','fishers.id', '=','details.fisher_id')
    ->leftjoin('species','species.id', '=', 'details.species_id')
    ->leftjoin('purposes','purposes.id', '=', 'details.purpose_id')
    ->leftjoin('islands','islands.id', '=', 'fishers.island_id')
    ->leftjoin('preservations','preservations.id', '=', 'details.preservation_id')   
    ->select('fishers.*','details.*','details.indate','islands.island_name','fishers.fisher_first_name','fishers.fisher_last_name','details.weight','species.species_name','purposes.purpose_name','preservations.preservation_name');
   }
```

I have tried to use `Month(details.indate) as Month, Year(details.indate) as Year` but seems not working. I used date as the datatype for `indate` and when I do `Month(details.indate) as Month` I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: COLUMN NOT FOUND: 1054 UNKNOWN COLUMN 'Month(details.indate)' IN 'field list' (SQL: SELECT fishers.* , details.* , MONTH(details.indate) AS MONTH

This is my datatable columns

```
   protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            [ 'data' => 'purpose_name', 'name' => 'purposes.purpose_name', 'title' => 'Purpose' ],
            [ 'data' => 'fisher_first_name', 'name' => 'fishers.fisher_first_name', 'title' => 'Fisher Name' ],
            [ 'data' => 'preservation_name', 'name' => 'preservations.preservation_name', 'title' => 'Preservation Methods' ],
            [ 'data' => 'species_name', 'name' => 'species.species_name', 'title' => 'Species Name' ],
            [ 'data' => 'island_name', 'name' => 'islands.island_name', 'title' => 'Island Name' ],
            [ 'data' => 'weight', 'name' => 'details.weight', 'title' => 'Weight' ],
            [ 'data' => 'indate', 'name' => 'details.indate', 'title' => 'Month' ],
            [ 'data' => 'indate', 'name' => 'details.indate', 'title' => 'Year' ],

        ];
    }
```

can someone help me how to do it?

Comment: What is the datatype for `details.indate`? Also what did it return when you do `Month(details.indate) as Month, Year(details.indate) as Year`?

Comment: I used date as the datatype for indate and when I do Month(details.indate) as Month I get this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Month(details.indate)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `fishers`.*, `details`.*, `Month(details`.`indate)` as `Month`,

Comment: So if you do without using `MONTH()` or `YEAR()` will the query work?

Comment: yes that correct

Comment: FYI you are using [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries), not [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent). You'll need to use [`raw` methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) if you want to use MySQL functions like `MONTH()` etc in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`DB::raw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) function to select expressions using Laravel Eloquent.

For example:

```
return $model->newQuery()->...
->select(DB::raw('Month(details.indate) as Month'), DB::raw('Year(details.indate) as Year'), 'fishers.*','details.*', ...)
```

Be sure to add `use DB;` at the top of your file.

Comment: This is really good and working thank you. all I have to do is have them reflected in my datatable as follows [ 'data' => 'Month', 'name' => 'details.indate', 'title' => 'Month' ],
            [ 'data' => 'Year', 'name' => 'details.indate', 'title' => 'Year' ],